# binding Select list in PartialView

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views

I need to generate a dynamic dropdown list in a partial view using ASP.NET MVC 2.

**controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetDestinationList()
        {
            JqGridClientRepository rep = new JqGridClientRepository();
            IEnumerable<Client> clients = rep.GetClients();
            var li = from s in clients
                     select new
                     {
                         Company = s.Company
                     };
            return PartialView(li);
        }
```

Below is the view i'm having currently and i need to bind the values to the select list returned by the controller.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>

   <select> 
    <option value="1">One</option> 
    <option value="2">Two</option> 
    ...
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always you could start by writing a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Values { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your controller action populate this view model and pass it to the view:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetDestinationList()
{
    JqGridClientRepository rep = new JqGridClientRepository();
    IEnumerable<Client> clients = rep.GetClients().ToList();
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.Values = clients.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = x.SomePropertyYouWantToBeUsedAsAValue,
        Value = x.SomePropertyYouWantToBeUsedAsText,
    });
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

and then make your view strongly typed to this view model and use the DropDownListFor helper:

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyViewModel>" 
%>
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.Values) %>
```

In the controller action you could perform whatever dynamic query you want to retrieve the data. The important bit is that you need to constitute an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` where each element represents respectively the Value and the Text used in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind like this, Your view will be like this:

```
<div class="form-field-bg">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ClientName)<div class="validate-star"></div>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ClientName, ViewBag.ClientList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "dropdown-field" })
            </div>
```